# How to join connected sub-paths by eliminate useless point with PaperJS?

Tags: paperjs

I have a path that draw a circle whose origin is in the "west" side, then I split by removing the top and bottom. Then I get three sub-paths:

1. Top-left 1/4 circle
2. Right half circle
3. Bottom-left 1/4 circle

But even visually 1 and 3 looks like a flipped 2, 1 and 3 are actually two sub-paths. How do I optimize this? I've tried smooth(), flatten() and simplify() and all not work.

Here is the [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/TZDNbsIwEIRfxcoFkJyVd/0P6qlnpEocSw/UcQkiOCiEVlXVd++aU2/2rL/Z8fw05XDJzbrZnfOc+kY2aezq/fMwieth7sWTKPlLPI+X63gv3QtLy8UWUUlDNinZBgXRWyRhAhhy0ckWrQIboiKB6CGi1qwFBOMNotjq4EBHGyUZAm21D8mzCWnvpVZALgQnkBQ4ZVCi4gPF+E8JBM44Il7PrhHReNGaCNZqHSVaAozeGNFWRGvC+GAsuxixJa1BkeegTgVwDp1JrWcfIg7QEvu44HWleQ+GyGINgUY7W9WKWxPrn+jB28Vqsy+1Lfi4D8P3Lg85zbnj7ubpnnm2L2kst3HIMIzH5eNl6k9DN+UCQy7HuV9tuPv3KR/O1/FU5luzfn37/QM=).

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, could you maybe illustrate what you are trying to achieve (e.g. before/after) ?

Comment: @sasensi Maybe I can simplify my question as, if I have a compound path that composes of two sub-paths A and B, the start of B is the same as the end of A, how do I simplify the path as a path that starts from start of A, and ends with end of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your simplified case, you just have to build a new path composed of all your sub paths segments.
In order to optimize the resulting path a bit, you can skip the first segment of path B and only keep its handle out, since it's the same than path A last segment.
Depending on your use case, you could also, with the same logic, skip the last segment of path B since it's the same than path A first segment and make sure that the resulting path is set to `closed`.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a possible implementation.

```js
const compoundPath = project.importJSON(
    ['CompoundPath', { 'applyMatrix': true, 'children': [['Path', { 'applyMatrix': true, 'segments': [[50, 700], [0, 700], [0, 600], [50, 600]] }], ['Path', { 'applyMatrix': true, 'segments': [[50, 600], [100, 600], [100, 700], [50, 700]] }]] }]
);
compoundPath.strokeColor = 'black';
project.activeLayer.addChild(compoundPath);

const subPaths = [];
compoundPath.children.forEach((child, i) => {
    subPaths.push(
        child
            .clone()
            .translate(0, 150)
            .addTo(project.activeLayer)
    );
});

const assembledPath = assembleSubPaths(subPaths);
assembledPath.strokeColor = 'black';

function assembleSubPaths(subPaths) {
    const path = new Path();
    subPaths.forEach((subPath) => {
        subPath.segments.forEach((segment, segmentIndex) => {
            const isFirstSegment = segmentIndex === 0;
            if (path.segments.length === 0 || !isFirstSegment) {
                path.add(segment);
            } else {
                path.lastSegment.handleOut = segment.handleOut;
            }
        });
        subPath.remove();
    });
    return path;
}
```